# Get path of file in Google Drive

Tags: google-colaboratory, drive

I have a file located at content/drive/Shareddrives/Bla/Bla/Bla/Bla/myfile.py

Is there an easy way to get the path of this file ? I can have like 10 subfolders and writing the path manually each time is a real pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for this task like this:

```py
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/content/drive"):
    for name in files:
        if name == "myfile.py":
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

/e: You can also copy a file path to clipboard from the left side menu `Files`. Right mouse click on chosen file and `Copy path`. Screenshot below, but with Polish language:

[image]

Comment: That is something that could work technically but it test all files in my drive. I have like several million files in my drive (company drive) so it's taking an eternity to get the path.

Also if there is 2 files with the same name it doesn't work.

Comment: You can change the top directory from `"/content/drive"` to something more specific. That way you can decrease a search time.

Comment: I edited my answer with another suggestion :-)

Comment: The other suggestion is pretty good, i'll accept it as an answer. Thank you for your time Pawel :)